# Selecting next element (KeyValue) in Dictionary by Value state starting from current [Linq]

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, unity-game-engine, c#-2.0

I was curious if there is more nice looking, simpler (? probably debatable in case with Linq :p) way to select any next Dictionary element that is not current selected.

Let's say I have a `Dictionary<string,bool>`, I have stored one of the default/first keys, now I need to select next element that has Value "true" (and start over if reached the end) ***without foreach/loop*** cycle.

I know that Dictionary isn't ordered but I don't care in this case. As long as `nextKey != currentKey` and the search goes further from `currentKey` rather than starting from `FirstOrDefault` (unless it is "the end" of Dictionary) I'm good for now.

**Example:**

```
public Dictionary<string,bool> myDic = new Dictionary<string,bool>(5);
myDic.Add("test1", false);
myDic.Add("test2", true);
myDic.Add("test3", false);
myDic.Add("test4", true);
myDic.Add("test5", true);
```

Now I select first Key and if it is true, I save it separately. *Otherwise OR on request* - I need to find next Key that has Value true starting from current selected. So let's say I select use `ElementAt(1)` and it is `test1`. Because `Value` is `false` I need to get next one that will be `true`, that's be `test2`. As I said, I'd like to avoid explicit loops like foreach/for/while/etc.

Comment: Could you provide sample input and output?

Comment: @SMA added example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is just select all the values with `value==true`,skip to the currentKey element,and then get the next element, something like:

```
public Dictionary<string,bool> myDic = new Dictionary<string,bool>(5);      
myDic.Add("test1", false);
myDic.Add("test2", true);
myDic.Add("test3", false);
myDic.Add("test4", true);
myDic.Add("test5", true);
string currentKey;
KeyValuePair<string,bool> res;
if (currentKey==null)
{
    res=myDic.Where(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
}
else
{
    res=myDic.Where(x => x.Value).SkipWhile(x => x.Key !=             
          currentKey).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
}
if (res.Key!=null)
{
     currentKey=res.Key;
     Console.WriteLine(currentKey);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Result is null");
}
```

Comment: Is ok, but that `x.Value == true` is redundant, just use `x.Value`

Comment: Hmm, seems to return null if first selected element has value False: http://csharppad.com/gist/02251f09b5751b1f3c3b22924baae799

Comment: @Digika yes, the first time you search for a value you just have to look for the first `Value==true` element. See my edit and this:http://csharppad.com/gist/604aec69ef98edb5ab16112441a7c9ff

Comment: Le Fantastique. Is it possible to make it work backwards if return results is null btw?

Comment: Well @Digika,the easiest way is to just `.Reverse()` your dictionary and search for the `currentKey`. I guess that would work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = yourDictionary.SkipWhile(_keyValue => _keyValue .Key != currentKey).Where(_keyValue => _keyValue.Value == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an enumerator :

```
            Dictionary<string, bool> dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

            List<string> keys = dict.Keys.AsEnumerable().ToList();
            List<string>.Enumerator dictEnumerator = keys.GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the idea of @Abdullah-dibas, this may work for you.

```
var m = myDic.SkipWhile(x => x.Value && x.Key != myDic.First().Key)?.First();
```

I've seen you are with C# 2.0, so a change is needed:

```
var m = myDic.SkipWhile(x => x.Value && x.Key != myDic.First().Key);
if (m != null && m.Count() > 0)
{
    var element = m.First();
    //And do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is: **No**, you cannot do it without using any *`foreach`/loop cycle*.
Consider that all linq-to-object codes are some kind of `foreach`/loop cycle.

But if you don't like to see those loop inside of your current page, you can make an extension method like this:

```
public static TKey GetNextKeyByValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, 
    TKey currentKey, TValue nextValue)
{
    var ckFounded = false;
    // if `currentkey` is last key of dictionary it will check for value from start again
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
        {
            if (ckFounded && pair.Value.Equals(nextValue))
            {
                return pair.Key;
            }
            if (pair.Key.Equals(currentKey) || (currentKey?.Equals(default(TKey)) ?? true))
            {
                ckFounded = true;
            }
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Key not found");
}
```

Use it like this:

```
//var nextKey = yourDictionary.GetNextKeyByValue(currentKey, nextValue);
var firstKey = myDic.GetNextKeyByValue(default(string) /* or null */, true);
var nextKey = myDic.GetNextKeyByValue(firstKey, true);
```